# Get values of an Array from an Observable

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I have an `Observable<MoviesResponse>`. My `MovieResponse` class contains a `getResults()` methods returning a `List<Result>`. This Result class has a `getTitle()` methods returning a String. I want to call the `getTitle()` methods of all my `Result` objects to get all the titles of my movies.

I achieved this with the code below using a foreach loop but I think there is a better way to do this by chaining RxJava operators, I just can't figure it out...

Subscription :

```
Observable<MoviesResponse> moviesResponseObservable = apiService.getTopRatedMoviesObservable(API_KEY);

subscription = moviesResponseObservable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<MoviesResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(MoviesResponse moviesResponse) {
                        List<Result> results = moviesResponse.getResults();
                        for (Result r:results) {
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG,r.getTitle());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Interface :

```
public interface ApiService {           
    @GET("movie/top_rated")
    Observable<MoviesResponse> getTopRatedMoviesObservable(@Query("api_key") String apiKey);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the following error with @zsmb13 answer :

> new Function : map (rx.functions.Func1) in
>   Observable cannot be applied to (anonymous
>   java.util.function.Function)reaso‌​n:
>   no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Function conforms to Func1

Anyway this answer was very helpul I just replaced `Function` with `Func1` and used `call` method.

```
subscription = moviesResponseObservable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMapIterable(new Func1<MoviesResponse, Iterable<Result>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Iterable<Result> call(MoviesResponse moviesResponse) {
                        return moviesResponse.getResults();
                    }

                })
                .map(new Func1<Result, String>() {

                    @Override
                    public String call(Result result) {
                        return result.getTitle();
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {


                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(String s) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, s);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [flatmap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) to transform your observable into an `Observable<Result>` and then use [map](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) to turn that into `Observable<String>`, which you can then subscribe to.

```
moviesReponseObservable
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMapIterable(new Function<MoviesResponse, Iterable<Result>>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<Result> apply(@NonNull MoviesResponse moviesResponse) throws Exception {
            return moviesResponse.getResults();
        }
    })
    .map(new Function<Result, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(@NonNull Result result) throws Exception {
            return result.getTitle();
        }
    })
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
            Log.d("TAG", s);
        }

        /* ... */    

    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was very useful. I got this error on both `new Function` : 
`map (rx.functions.Func1<? super com.example.reactiveprog.network.apimodel.Result,? extends R>)
in Observable cannot be applied to (anonymous java.util.function.Function<com.example.reactiveprog.network.apimodel.Result,java.lang.String>)reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Function<Result, String> conforms to Func1<? super Result, ? extends R>` but find a way with `Func1` following Android Studio suggestions.